# Проблема с переиспользованием ячейки UITableViewCell. Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview

Всем привет. Не могу разобраться с переиспользованием ячейки tableView. 
С сервера приходит сообщение, после которого должна удаляться кнопка в tableViewCell. 
Вот функция, которая запускается, когда приходит сообщение с сервера:

```
func contactHasHadCanceled(indexOfCanceledMessage: Int) {
   print("Game Maker has canceled the word \(messages[indexOfCanceledMessage].word)")
   messages[indexOfCanceledMessage].isAbleToBeInteracted = false
   let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexOfCanceledMessage, section: 0)
   tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) 
}
```

Вот cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell
  cell.delegate = self
  cell.configure(message: self.messages[indexPath.row], playerType: self.playerType, index: indexPath.row)
  return cell
}
```

Вот функции настройки ячейки (Находятся в ContactCell):

```
private var contactCellButton: UIButton!

func configure(message: Message, playerType: PlayerType, index: Int) {
  self.playerType = playerType
  self.indexRow = index
  setUpDefinitionLabel()
  print(message.isAbleToBeInteracted)
  if message.isAbleToBeInteracted {
    setUpButton()
  } else {
   unSetUpButton()
  }
  definitionLabel.text = message.definition
 }

func setUpButton() {
  contactCellButton = UIButton()
  contactCellButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  addSubview(contactCellButton)
  contactCellButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
  contactCellButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
  contactCellButton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
  contactCellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
  switch playerType {
  case .none:
    print("player type in contact cell is not defined")
  case .some(.player):
    contactCellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    contactCellButton.setTitle("Contact", for: .normal)
  case .some(.gameMaker):
    contactCellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    contactCellButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
 }

  //Cornstraints
  contactCellButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
  contactCellButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: definitionLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
  contactCellButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
  contactCellButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
}

func unSetUpButton() {
  contactCellButton = nil
}
```

Проблема в том, что при скроллинге удаленные кнопки снова появляются. Также не все кнопки удаляются. Не могу понять, почему идет неправильное переиспользование.

Я пытался сделать так:

```
setUpButton()
contactCellButton.isHidden = !message.isAbleToBeInteracted
```

Вместо:

```
 if message.isAbleToBeInteracted {
      setUpButton()
   } else {
      unSetUpButton()
   }
```

И сделал проверку нахардкоденным массивом c разными экземплярами Message, где есть isAbleToBeInteracted и true и false.
Результат все тот же: сначала появляется таблица с правильным отображением кнопок, но при скроллинге все кнопки появляются, не смотря на значение message.isAbleToBeInteracted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте примерно вот это:

```
func configure(message: Message, playerType: PlayerType, index: Int) {
    self.playerType = playerType
    self.indexRow = index
    setUpDefinitionLabel()
    print(message.isAbleToBeInteracted)
    cell.contactCellButton = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(111)
    if message.isAbleToBeInteracted {
        setUpButton(contactCellButton)
    } else {
        contactCellButton?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    definitionLabel.text = message.definition
}

func setUpButton(contactCellButton: UIButton?) {
    if (contactCellButton == nil)
    {
        contactCellButton = UIButton()
        contactCellButton.tag = 111;
        cell.contentView.addSubview(contactCellButton)
        contactCellButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contactCellButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        contactCellButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        contactCellButton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        contactCellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    switch playerType {
        case .none:
            print("player type in contact cell is not defined")
        case .some(.player):
            contactCellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            contactCellButton.setTitle("Contact", for: .normal)
        case .some(.gameMaker):
            contactCellButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            contactCellButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Пояснение:

Вам надо один раз создать UIButton. При обработке каждой ячейки вы достаете  contactCellButton из ячейки cell с помощью функции viewWithTag. Если UIButton еще не создан, создаете и добавляете в cell. Если создана, просто меняете параметры или оформление.

Если кнопку показывать не надо, вы ее должны удалить с ячейки функцией removeFromSuperview.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант заработал хорошо. Но у меня странная вещь, при скроллинге таблице вверх-вниз память забивается и не очищается. Это ведь не нормально?

Comment: @FedyaGrab это нормально. Главное чтобы она очистилась после завершения работы экрана.